# How to Stop a Workflow from Generating Another Workflow - SharePoint 2010

Tags: workflow

I have two lists, Parent and Child, and both are using InfoPath to create items.

- When an item is created on either list a SharePoint Designer workflow also creates the same item on the other list.
- As you may guess, when one workflow  creates or updates an item on the other list, the other list's workflow gets triggered and auto generates its workflow, which creates a duplicate item on the original list.  Each workflow uses the others items ID.
- **Example:**  **IF Child:ParentID equals Current Item: ID then update item in Child….Else ..IF Child:ParentID not equals Current Item:ID then create item in Child**

How do I prevent duplicating the list items?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query (lookup) to make sure the item doesn't already exist in the other list first.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Define-a-workflow-lookup-d7fcc0dd-6e2d-4e10-bd07-f22627f5c2f3#bm4

Use an If statement and only proceed when the item doesn't exist.

Comment: I may not understand it fully but the item will always exist on eather list.  When either list items is created or modified, it creates or modifies the item on the other list.  I want to prevent the workflow from starting again on the other list item.

Comment: The point is, before either workflow creates an item in the other list, query to see if it's already there.  If it is, don't create another one.